# Automatically populate Age field in postgres DB from birth date in django module

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models

I'm new to Django and i'm working on web app for Employee data set. So i have 'birth_date' field in my model and i want to calculate Age based on birth date & also store the age in postgres database and age should automatically update in database. So how can i do this in django?

here is my models.py
`class Test_Employee(models.Model):

```
name= models.CharField(max_length=100)
birthdate = models.DateField()
age= models.IntegerField()
address= models.TextField()
Confirmation= models.BooleanField(default=False)`
```

So here i want to take birth_date from user and calculate Age and also store it in database. And Database should also show me the current Age whenever i query for that record.

Comment: Do you have an age field in the Postgres table and what type is it?  What is your Django model for ```Employee```?

Comment: I have an age field in postgres with integer datatype where i want to store age in years. But i'm making this model just for learning purpose, so i can change the datatypes as required. I just want to know how can i populate age automatically in postgres DB from django.

Comment: See answer below for one solution.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way is to not get Django involved. Postgres has an age function:

```
select age('08/08/2020'::date, '03/25/2001'::date);
  age           
-------------------------
 19 years 4 mons 14 days

---Which you can use to get the years as integer:

select date_part('years', age('08/08/2020'::date, '03/25/2001'::date))::int;
date_part 
-----------
        19
--Or short form. Uses now() as first date:

select date_part('years', age('03/25/2001'::date))::int;
date_part 
-----------
        19
```

Put that in a trigger function and let Postgres do the work:

```
create table age_test(bday date, age_yrs integer);

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.age_calc()
 RETURNS trigger
 LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
    age_int integer;
BEGIN

    SELECT INTO
        age_int
    date_part('years', age(NEW.bday))::int;

    NEW.age_yrs = age_int;
RETURN NEW;
END;
$function$

create trigger 
   age_yrs 
before insert or update on 
  age_test 
for each row execute 
   function age_calc();

insert into age_test (bday) values ('03/25/2001');

select * from age_test ;
    bday    | age_yrs 
------------+---------
 03/25/2001 |      19
```

Comment: Thanks Adrian for the answer. As I'm new to postgres, I have one doubt, what if i populate age in days & I don't make any changes to that particular record in database and I want to query for this record afterwards, so it will give me static value which was stored while insert/update. Is there any way to apply triggers on SELECT statement as well so that i'll get dynamic value for age every time i query for this record?

Comment: Well if you want the age calculation/result to change then you are looking at [annotate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.annotate) and/or [F](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/expressions/#f-expressions) expressions.  Or setting a property or method on the model.